# How to use Stream.iter to process lines from stdin in OCaml

Tags: stream, ocaml, stdin

I'm trying to process data from stdin in a line-oriented fashion in OCaml, but I'm having trouble getting the types to line up using `Stream.iter`. I found the following code snippet on the OCaml website (http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/streams.html):

```
let line_stream_of_channel channel =
    Stream.from
      (fun _ ->
         try Some (input_line channel) with End_of_file -> None)
```

Using this, I've written a simple function that reads a line does a few things, and prints some data back. I'll elide the details, since I believe the function works just fine. It should have the type `string -> unit`, though, just like (for example) `print_endline`, and the error I'm getting from the compiler is the same whether I pass my function or `print_endline` to `Stream.iter`.

Here's the call:

```
let read_data =
  Stream.iter ~f:print_summary (line_stream_of_channel In_channel.stdin)
```

The error I get from the compiler is this:

```
Error: The function applied to this argument has type 'a Stream.t -> unit
This argument cannot be applied with label ~f
```

I've used Stream.iter in the past without any trouble. It's confusing that it thinks `print_endline` has the type `'a Stream.t -> unit` - it should be `string -> unit`, right?

Comment: The other problem I had (mentioned in my reply below) was that my `print_summary` function was of type `string -> unit`, but as defined, `line_stream_of_channel` created a stream of `string option -> unit`. In fact, for processing stdin data using `Stream.iter`, I want the line stream to return a line or EOF, not some or none as implemented. The eventual solution was to remove the option wrapping around the lines and just use `Stream.from`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function with type `'a Stream.t -> unit` is `Stream.iter`. Basically the compiler is telling you that `Stream.iter` doesn't have any named parameters. You're trying to pass it a parameter named `f`, so that's the problem.

The solution would be to delete `~f:`. (I haven't tested because I don't have your code.)

Comment: Doh. You're right, thanks. The code still isn't working but the problem is now somewhere else. If I find that there's another obvious bug in any of the code that I've actually posted here, I'll correct it with a note.